# Dynamic Ranking with tiers in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have the following data:

| ID | company | value | tier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | tier 1 |
| 3 | A | 5 | tier 3 |
| 4 | A | 2 | tier 2 |
| 8 | A | 3 | tier 2 |
| 2 | C | 9 | tier 4 |
| 5 | D | 10 | tier 4 |
| 7 | B | 2 | tier 2 |

Tier is a calculated column:

```
tier = 
SWITCH (
TRUE (),
table[value] < max(table[value]) * 0.25, "tier 1",
table[value] < max(table[value]) * 0.50, "tier 2",
table[value] < max(table[value]) * 0.75, "tier 3",
"tier 4"
)
```

If i filter my data through slicers then not all rows of my data are being considered, meaning that instead of recalculating tiers for the filtered data, one or more of my tiers go missing. For example, if i use the slicers and choose only 2 companies:

| ID | company | value | tier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | tier 1 |
| 3 | A | 5 | tier 3 |
| 4 | A | 2 | tier 2 |
| 8 | A | 3 | tier 2 |
| 7 | B | 2 | tier 2 |

I have no tier 4, because the max value is a company that is not selected. I've tried creating a secondary filtered table but i'm having trouble applying the filters through the slicers. How can i make this dynamic in order to always have all the tiers available?

Answer (score 0):

I have reperformed your calculation, although the result for the tier is slightly different (perhaps you key wrong value? ), regardless of the result, your issue can solved by create a new table so that the `tier` won't affected by filter by always have `max value` of 10, here is the solution and accept the result if help :)

1)Suppose my original table is `sheet1`, I create a new table from it

```
Table = Sheet1
```

2)On the new table, I add new column for the tier ranking

```
tier = 
SWITCH (
TRUE (),
'Table'[value] < max(Sheet1[value]) * 0.25, "tier 1",
'Table'[value] < max(Sheet1[value]) * 0.50, "tier 2",
'Table'[value] < max(Sheet1[value]) * 0.75, "tier 3",
"tier 4"
)
```

3)The new table

[image]

4)The table report will still have tier3 & tier4 after filter :)

[image]